# Set Method isn't protected, how do I make it protected?

Tags: c#, class, oop

I started writing a Person class for an end of year Project, I found a basic getset property from a previous project, but it has in a UML comment that the method currently has no protection.

Is this is simple as changing "public" to "Protected"? or am I missing something?

```
//PROPERTIES

    /// <summary>
    /// Property for "Title"
    /// Read & Write property for attribute "Title"
    /// set method currently has no protection
    /// </summary>
    ///
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }
    
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstname; }
        set { firstname = value; }
    }
    
    public string MiddleName
    {
        get { return middlename; }
        set { middlename = value; }
    }
    
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastname; }
        set { lastname = value; }
    }
```

PS. I'm in a basic OOP course, it's very simple code (My project only requires ONE property :P), I've never used validation within a get/set before, I'll look into it, but I think:

*`"protected set {title = value; }"`*

was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: That depends on the *definition* of `protection` of the person writing that comment. Does it have protection from *invalid input*, or *invalid use*, or *other*? If they want the `set` method protected from use outside the class, use `protected set`.

Comment: Could you post the full class? I think I know what they want you to do but I need to see the full class in order to confirm it.

Comment: I've edited in your code in the text of the question and removed the link to your image. You should use text to represent code instead of a screenshot in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure protected is what you want, and not `private`? `protected` is intended for classes used for inheritance, and in any case I can think of regarding representing people, composition over inheritance would be better.

Comment: Well, the attributes in Person eventually becomes part of a member, Person has an Address and Details class it inherits from. I'm not a very experienced programmer, but It both inherits and is inherited.

Comment: _was exactly what I was looking for_  - what benefit do you think it brings?

Comment: I'm hoping that protected will offer more protection so that the attribute cannot be changed as easily.

Comment: Then why not make it `private` ?

Comment: Wouldn't that make it inaccessible?

Comment: It would be readonly from outside the class, and that's what 'protection' means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you can have different protection for setters and getters:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; protected set; }   
}
```

This will allow any class to read Name, but only Person or derivatives to write it. Here I am using an auto-property, but a similar construction can be used with backing fields.

Comment: It is not clear from the question if the OP is referring to literally ` protected` property, or some other concept.

Comment: didn't know you could individually give protection to a get/set, thanks for this!

Comment: Agreed - should get clarification as to whether or not the comment about protection meant that there was no validation in the setter, or that the setter should be "protected"

Comment: You can indeed have different combined read/write protection. This is the way to go if you want to make your class immutable, which is often a good design choice. Even for mutable classes it is often a good choise to limit who will be allowed to update the properties.

Answer (score 3):

From this

```
/// set method currently has no protection
public string Title
{
    get { return title; }
    set { title = value; }
}
```

I would guess that protection is not about the `protected` access-modifier but about data validation.

Validation can take many different forms, one possible form would look like

```
public string Title
{
    get { return title; }
    set 
    { 
        if (value == title)  
          return;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
          throw new ArgumentException("Title");
        title = value;  
    }
}
```

Comment: value == title will throw a NullReferenceException if value is null. Equals(value, title) is normally a better property equality pattern.

Comment: @Holstebroe - no it won't throw, try it. And it isn't better, that `Equals()` is very, very rarely needed but everybody is polluting all their code with it nowadays. And using it all the time makes it lose its signal function.

Comment: You are right. Only if operator == is overloaded, == will throw an exception and not for strings.

Comment: I think the overuse of equals comes from the Java advice of "how do I compare strings in Java?"

Comment: @jdphenix - and from ReSharper property generators and guidelines. Code generators go for the safest code, not always for the cleanest. But I guess that when you want guidelines that people should blindly follow, Equals() is OK.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - If you are working with e.g. WPF or Entity Framework, there can be a penalty involved if you are assigning a semantically equal value to a property. Here I would argue, that Equals is safer, since overriding Equals is the common practice for implementing semantic comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You want to protect your class's data from mutation from the outside. In OOP parlance this is known as [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Consider this code snippet:

```
sealed class Person {
    public Person(string name) { 
        this.name = name; 
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; } 
}
```

- An instance of `Person` cannot be mutated from the outside. As it is an instance of `Person` is immutable.
- Derived from above, code that uses `Person` doesn't have to worry about risking editing a `Person`:

  `Person p = new Person('Bob');`
  `p.Name = 'Sally' // won't work, set is not accessible`

Other notes:

You probably don't want literally `protected`. It's use case is when you have a class which is intended for inheritance. If you're representing people in a data model, you don't want to use it.

In your comments, you stated you wanted to derive a class `Address` from a `Person`. That is an inappropriate relationship to establish. Consider this plain English sentence.

> An address is also a person.

Nonsense, right? What about this one:

> A person has an address.

Makes much more sense. [More related reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle).

So in this sense, you would establish the `HAS-A` relationship with composition - an address would be a member of a `Person`.

```
sealed class Person {
    public Address HomeAddress {get; private set;} 

    //.. and other members
}
```

The above establishes that again, code outside of a `Person` instance cannot mutate the address*, and a `Person` has an `Address`, which makes sense in this context.

*This is true in the sense that the `HomeAddress` reference is immutable from the outside, but the `Address` object it refers to is not. To avoid confusion and FUBAR later, make sure `Address` is also immutable.